Does loading into factory settings remove installed addons?
I know when you reset blender to factory defaults it will uncheck all installed addons, but does it remove them from the files (in other words do i have to reinstall all of the addons I've installed after I factory reset.)

Not sure why you are asking this instead of just testing. It's very easy to see this for yourself.

@MartynasŽiemys I just want to make sure they don’t get removed or I will have to take an extra hour scrolling on the internet just to find the addons I need.

That's reasonable. When you load factory settings, they are not saved automatically. You have to go to Preferences and hit Save Preferences to override your preferences. If you are worried about loosing your preferences for any reason, you can make a backup of your preferences folder. It's in %appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender if you are on Windows. Just copy the folder with the version number somewhere safe so you can restore it if needed. That's where add-ons are stored as well.

You can paste %appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender into windows run menu(winlogo+r) or file explorer's address bar to go to the actual folder which is usually C:\Users\[Your user name]\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender.

@MartynasŽiemys Thank you!

No. They remain installed and you can enable them in the Prefrences( Ctrl  +  , ), Add-ons tab.
